# django: changing settings while running

Tags: django, django-settings

Is there a problem to change one of the settings when django is running?

For example, I'd like to change `REGISTRATION_OPEN` from the `django-registration` app from False to True when it is live.
I do not want to stop the server to change this value.

Is there a cache that would prevent the new value to be used?

Should I rather consider a table to store settings that can be changed when it is live?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django Livesettings is an excellent option: http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html

Comment: ok that's what I thought, having the settings in the DB sounds better. thanks.